# how to print duplicate values of a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose this list:

```py
list1 = [
{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'B'},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'A', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
{'id': 4, 'name': 'C', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
{'id': 5, 'name': 'E', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
{'id': 6, 'name': 'B', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'B'}
]
```

I'm going to find if both values of `name` and `type` are the same.

This is expected output:

```
name A has duplicate type A
name B has duplicate type B
```

How can I have the expected output?

I googled but most of results print one value only (for example if there are multiple `name` keys with the same values).

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana I see something like https://statisticsglobe.com/find-remove-duplicates-list-dictionaries-python but it is for one value only.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()` to make a dictionary whose keys are the tuples `(name, type)`. Then print all the elements with count > 1.

Comment: @Barmar when I run `collections.Counter(list1)`, I have `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` error. I even tried `dict(collections.Counter(list1))` but got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dictionary whose keys are the names and types, and values are the repetition counts. Then show the ones with counts more than 1.

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'B'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'A', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'C', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'E', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 6, 'name': 'B', 'blob': 'blob', 'type': 'B'}
]

counts = Counter((x['name'], x['type']) for x in list1)
for (n, t), count in counts.items():
    if count > 1:
        print(f"name {n} has duplicate type {t}")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` error when I run. Do you please check again?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call `.items()`